# Using <router-link> with vue-custom-element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm very new to Vue and am trying to create a Vue app that can be embedded inside a non Vue app so I am using vue-custom-element. I am having trouble getting routing to work inside of my Vue app widget.

I have two components in my app - Schools and School.

in main.js I have this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element'
import Schools from "./components/Schools";
import School from "./components/Schools";

Vue.use(vueCustomElement);
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      { path: '/', component: Schools },
      { path: '/school', component: School },
    ]
  })
App.router = router;
Vue.customElement('schools-widget', App)
```

and then in my schools component (Schools.vue) I have

```
<router-link to="/school">School</router-link>
```

which I was hoping would link me from my Schools component to my School component.

But I get the error

```
Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component correctly?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should pass `router` as a parameter to `new Vue` instance, not to `App` component.

Comment: @IgorMoraru can I use "new Vue" when I am using Vue.customElement in this way?  Do you have an example?

Comment: sorry, this is my bad. you can't. disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject the router to the component like that:

```
Vue.customElement('schools-widget', {
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

---

Update 1:
Just found out that you forgot to install the Vue router plugin:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that (by the way I have installed VueRouter)

Comment: No, I mean install vue router plugin by `Vue.use`

Comment: not sure what you mean - I installed the router by running npm install vue-router and then I imported it in main.js ?

Comment: But you forgot to "use" it. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html
That's what I mean

Comment: I do use it - it is used in main.js, I import it and add it to the app ?  What do you mean by "use" it?

Comment: For more information: https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html#npm

You forgot this line: `Vue.use(VueRouter)`

Comment: That does not work, I tried that.  According to the vue-custom-element plugin issues I am not supposed to do that? https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element/issues/32

Comment: Guess what? It's work for me.
The code that the author answer has been pruned. As you can see, he did not import anything, did not declare `router` or `store`.

Comment: Hmm, its not working for me - would you be willing to share your main.js?

Comment: I've just made an example. https://github.com/linhx/demo-vue-custom-component-router.

You should read README.md for an example.

Answer (score -3):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import Schools from "./components/Schools";
import School from "./components/Schools";

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      { path: '/', component: Schools },
      { path: '/school', component: School },
    ]
  })
new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

I think your code should be like this.

Comment: Thanks but that does not user vue-custom-element which is what I need to use